# how to optimze my page without causing too much re render in react/next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-select, zustand

Hello I got my react page code to edit user profile it has a dropdown selector from react-select library and an input text box. as for my state management i use zustand. My page run  just fine for its purpose and function but when i add my dropdown component i realized it re render too much.

is there any possible way to improve my code so it wont cause too much re render?

this is my code

src\app(dashboard)\my-profile\page.tsx

```
"use client";
import InputTexColProfile from "@/app/(dashboard)/my-profile/components/inputTextBoxCol";
import DDSearch from "@/app/(dashboard)/my-profile/components/DDSearch";
import changeHandler from "./scripts/changeHandlerDD";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { userStore } from "@/stores/userStore";
import { organisasiStore } from "@/stores/organisasiStore";
import { fetchListUser } from "@/stores/userStore";
import TextInputHandler from "./scripts/changeHandlerInput";

const UserProfile = () => {
  const { user, listUsers } = userStore((state) => state);
  const { fetchOrganisasi, direktorat, departemen, divisi } = organisasiStore(
    (state) => state
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!listUsers){
      fetchListUser()
    }
    if(!direktorat || !departemen || !divisi){
      fetchOrganisasi();
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('render user profile')

  // if (user && direktorat && departemen && divisi && listUsers) {
    return (
      <div className="flex-col w-full h-full max-h-[100%] justify-center">
        <div className="flex justify-center p-5">
          {!user?.adminValidation ? (
            <p className="text-wrap text-center text-xl font-extrabold text-[#A70000] w-[40%]">
              Akun anda belum tervalidasi oleh Admin Mohon buat request dan
              hubungi admin layum
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p className="text-wrap text-center text-xl font-extrabold text-lightblue w-[40%]">
              Akun anda telah tervalidasi
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-2 justify-evenly mx-auto h-[70%] w-[80%] bg-lightblue rounded-[20px]">
          <div className="grid grid-rows-3 rounded-[20px] w-[45%] my-auto h-[80%] items-center bg-lighterblue">
            <InputTexColProfile
              label="name"
              text="Nama"
              defaultVal={user?.name}
              TextInputHandler={TextInputHandler}
              disabled={false}
            />
            <DDSearch
              label="atasan"
              text="Nama Atasan"
              isMulti={false}
              dataArr={listUsers}
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
            />
            <InputTexColProfile
              label="jabatan"
              text="Jabatan"
              defaultVal={user?.jabatan}
              TextInputHandler={TextInputHandler}
              disabled={false}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-rows-3 rounded-[20px] w-[45%] my-auto h-[80%] items-center bg-lighterblue">
            <DDSearch
              label="direktorat"
              text="Direktorat"
              isMulti={false}
              dataArr={direktorat}
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
            />
            {/* <DDSearch
              label="divisi"
              text="Divisi"
              isMulti={false}
              dataArr={divisi}
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
            /> */}
            {/* <DDSearch
              label="departemen"
              text="Departemen"
              isMulti={false}
              dataArr={departemen}
              changeHandler={changeHandler}
            /> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  // } else {
  //   return <h1>Loading</h1>
  // }
};

export default UserProfile;
```

src\app(dashboard)\my-profile\components\DDSearch.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import LabelBox from "@/app/(dashboard)/my-profile/components/LabelBox";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Select = dynamic(() => import('react-select'), {
  ssr: false,
})

interface Props {
  isMulti: boolean;
  dataArr: any;
  label: string;
  text: string;
  changeHandler: (context: string, data: any) => void
}

interface OptionsE {
  value: any;
  label: string;
}

type Options = OptionsE[];

const DDSearch = ({ label, text, isMulti, dataArr, changeHandler }: Props) => {
  console.log('render ' + label)
  let options: Options
  if (Array.isArray(dataArr)) {
    options = dataArr.map((e) => {
      return {
        value: e,
        label: `${e.name}`,
      };
    });
    return (
      <div className="flex-col w-full justify-start ms-5 max-w-[90%]">
        <LabelBox forLabel={label} text={text} />
        <Select
          id={label}
          isMulti={isMulti}
          options={options}
          onChange={(e: any) => {
            changeHandler(label, e.value);
          }}
          name="colors"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default DDSearch;
```

src\app(dashboard)\my-profile\scripts\changeHandlerDD.ts

```
import { setUser, userStore } from "@/stores/userStore";

const changeHandler = (context: string, data: any) => {
  const userdata = userStore.getState().user;
  let obj: any;
  switch (context) {
    case "atasan":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        atasan: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;

    case "direktorat":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        direktorat: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;

    case "divisi":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        divisi: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;
      
    case "departemen":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        departemen: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return

    default:
      return;
  }
};

export default changeHandler;
```

Thanks before

Answer (score -1):

cool new

```js
import { setUser, userStore } from "@/stores/userStore";

const changeHandler = (context: string, data: any) => {
  const userdata = userStore.getState().user;
  let obj: any;
  switch (context) {
    case "atasan":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        atasan: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;

    case "direktorat":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        direktorat: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;

    case "divisi":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        divisi: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return;
      
    case "departemen":
      obj = {
        ...userdata,
        departemen: data.name,
      };
      setUser(obj);
      return

    default:
      return;
  }
};

export default changeHandler;
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to the solution, otherwise it will be down voted

Comment: sure ,it's very kind of u to remind me . the new answer i will post in next. hope it will be helpful . thks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).